# Asciidoc editor wih file structure panel

Tags: editor, asciidoc

Is there an AsciiDoc editor (for linux) with a panel where the current open document is parsed and its structure is shown, so that I can jump there and there in large documents ?

Note: I'm not asking an opinion (e.g. what's best), but simply which (if any) editor have this exact feature.

Answer (score 2):

The [Atom editor](https://atom.io/) supports AsciiDoc outlines through the [document-outline](https://atom.io/packages/document-outline) package.
There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/asciidoctor/atom-asciidoc-assistant/issues/16) to get it installed by default when one install the meta-package [asciidoc-assistant](https://atom.io/packages/asciidoc-assistant), but for now one has to install it manually.

Also, an other editor that support outlines is [ASciiDocFx](https://asciidocfx.com/).

Answer (score 0):

VS Code 1.25 and above supports AsciiDoc outlines when you have the better-asciidoctor-vscode extension installed. Details about the extension:

- https://github.com/bcherny/better-asciidoctor-vscode
- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bcherny.better-asciidoc-vscode

Details about VS Code Outline View, which is displayed at the bottom of the VS Code explorer:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_outline-view